# jenkins start django server after successful build

Tags: django, jenkins, virtualenv

We use `jenkins` as continious integration system. We have two django servers validated by `jenkins`.
`jenkins` validates successully the first server. The second server depends on the first one. Thus we would like to launch at the end of the first server validation the first server itself.

We are using python, virtualenv and django and defined the `Virtualenv Builder` as follow:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
rm -f .coverage
fab localhost test
coverage xml
nohup python manage.py runserver 9090 &
```

The issue is that the build never ends due to the nohup.

How can I launch the server after a successful build?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Ken,

I tried using fabric, but again python manage.py runserver - runs continuosly, so the next command is not starting.

And just few mins ago my collegue showed me how to use **nohup** and with variable **BUILD_ID** of Jenkins it would be like this to get Success from the build and leave the Django server running:

BUILD_ID=dontKillMe nohup python manage.py runserver host_server &

This worked for our Django project testing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using *fabric* to test, I would recommend defining another *fabric task*, say, **deploy**, which you could call assuming the build succeeds.

Much like the call to `fab` completes for a successful build such that you get to the `nohup` line, I would expect the **deploy** task to return also.

You may also want to consider making the server a *service* (either via an */etc/init.d* style script, or *upstart* if Ubuntu), and have the *fabric* task stop the currently running one, copy over whatever new files it needs (or similar process), and then restart it.

Assuming what you have above is a *bash* script or similar, you may want to also define `set -e` so that, in case any of the commands returns a non-success code, the script will fail, and in turn, fail the build.